Cannot reach port of container running in host mode
I've been trying to run homebridge in a container on a raspberry pi, here is the docker-compose.yaml definition:
services:
  homebridge:
    image: homebridge/homebridge:latest
    container_name: homebridge
    restart: always
    network_mode: host
    environment:
      - PGID=1099
      - PUID=1099
      - HOMEBRIDGE_CONFIG_UI=1
      - HOMEBRIDGE_CONFIG_UI_PORT=8581
    volumes:
      - /raid/config/homebridge:/homebridge

The application starts successfully and I can see in the logs that the HTTP server is up and running:
[10/3/2024, 10:30:14 PM] [Homebridge UI] Homebridge UI v4.59.0 is listening on :: port 8581

Now if I curl the port I get a connection refused:
$ curl localhost:8581
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8581: Connection refused

What doesn't make sense to me is that if I exec into the container and do the exact same thing, the call goes through:
$ docker exec -it 3783843255f7 /bin/bash
Note: This is a restricted shell, sudo cannot be used here.

Homebridge Terminal

Node.js Version: v20.17.0
Node.js Path: /opt/homebridge/bin/node
Plugin Path: /var/lib/homebridge/node_modules

Update Node.js: hb-service update-node

Install Plugin: hb-service add homebridge-plugin-name
Remove Plugin: hb-service remove homebridge-plugin-name

root@tardis:/homebridge $ curl localhost:8581
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
...

Why isn't the 8581 port accessible from the outside even though the container is running in host network mode?

How is docker running? snap? rootless? docker desktop?

It's running rootless


It's running rootless

That's a different network namespace:

Host network (docker run --net=host) is also namespaced inside RootlessKit.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/#known-limitations
When docker is running rootless, inside of a container (docker-in-docker, snap), inside a VM (docker desktop, or accessing a remote docker engine), then localhost for the docker engine is not the same as localhost of the user executing the CLI.
